# add anonymous object to an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know to add a named object to an existing JavaScript object you do this:

```
var json = {};
json.a = {name:"a"};
```

But how can you add an object to an existing JavaScript object in a similar fashion without assigning it an associative name, so that it could be accessed by a `for()` statement. Sorry if I'm being a little vague, I don't know a lot about JavaScript objects.

**UPDATE:**
I want the end result to look like this:

```
var json = [{name:'a'}{name:'b'}];
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)?

Comment: no, i want the objects added to be seperate objects

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: **This is not JSON.** http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/ *Edit:* I "corrected" the post, if you think it changes the meaning, please roll back.

Comment: Your end result is simply an array of objects.

Comment: @felix nice link, this has always bugged me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an array that you push an item on to using

```
myArrayVar.push(value);
```

or

```
myArrayVar[myArrayVar.length] = value;
```

Answer (score 6):

What you have there is not strictly a JSON object. You're using JS object literals rather.

You can do this:

```
var jsObj = {};

// add a 'name' property
jsObj = { name: 'a'};

var anotherObj = { other: "b" };

// will add 'other' proprty to jsObj
$.extend(jsObj, anotherObj);
// jsObj becomes - {name: 'a', other:'b'}
```

The **JSON** representation of above will look like:

```
var jsonString = "{'name': 'a', 'other':'b'}";

// will give you back jsObj.
var jsonObj = JSON.Parse(jsonString); // eval(jsonString) in older browsers
```

Note that you cannot have property without a name. This is not valid:

```
// invalid, will throw error
jsObj = { : 'a'};
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to have a property of an object without a property name. A "for ... in" loop is a loop over that collection of property names, after all. That is,

```
for (var k in obj)
```

will set "k" equal to each of the **names** of properties in "obj" in turn.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, because a JSON object is a collection of string-value pairs. A value can be an array, and you can push your object into that array, without an associative name.

http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is an array of objects.

```
var j = [{name:'a'},{name:'b'}];
```

This has the properties you are looking for. You can operate on it like so:

```
for(var i in j) {
    alert(j[i].name);
}
```

Comment: Don't iterate over an array with `for...in`. Use a normal `for` loop instead.